# Python 3.9 and Pycharm, HTMLParser AttributeError

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.9

When trying to create new python 3.9 Virtualenv Environment in Pycharm I got such error

```
AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/6g/vnvmvlf51gv49m22rzj9zdtw0000gn/T/tmpifdsjw6lpycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/private/var/folders/6g/vnvmvlf51gv49m22rzj9zdtw0000gn/T/tmpifdsjw6lpycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/private/var/folders/6g/vnvmvlf51gv49m22rzj9zdtw0000gn/T/tmpifdsjw6lpycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "/private/var/folders/6g/vnvmvlf51gv49m22rzj9zdtw0000gn/T/tmpifdsjw6lpycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .py33compat import Bytecode
  File "/private/var/folders/6g/vnvmvlf51gv49m22rzj9zdtw0000gn/T/tmpifdsjw6lpycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 55, in <module>
    unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
```

What can be done with it?

Comment: 1: Which version of PyCharm? 2: You might want to update setuptools.

Comment: @Matthias - 1) 2019.2 2) Can you help me with this? Some instructions

Comment: A comment on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751439/htmlparser-htmlparser-unescape-doesnt-work says that it is `html.unescape` in Python 3. So it looks like you are trying to execute Python 2 code in a Python 3 environment.

Comment: It works for me with PyCharm 2020.3 and setuptools 51.1.1. In your console you can update setuptools with `pip install setuptools --upgrade`.

Comment: @Matthias - thanks. I have to do both, update pycharm and setuptools. If you want, you can post an answer based on your comment, and I will accept it

Comment: I'm no point hunter. Having that as a comment is enough. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 'pip3 install netifaces' failing on Debian 10 Buster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040971/why-is-pip3-install-netifaces-failing-on-debian-10-buster)

Comment: @bad_coder - actually, it affects some Pycharm settings. So, the link to the answer you've provided, does not fully answer my question

Comment: @Headmaster I googled the error, the removal of `HTMLParser().unescape` from Python 3.9 caused an incompatibility with a specific version of setuptools, that is resolved by upgrading the versions. There are countless scenarios where this error can occur but the cause and solution is always the same - upgrade to the latest versions. (But you are right, I'm retracting my close vote because in this case PyCharm itself needs to be updated.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on **Matthias** comment

To fix this error I have to update both pycharm (>=2020) and setuptools (>=41).

Hope this will help somebody

Comment: For reference ticket [PY-39579 on JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39579).

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading to a newer version of PyCharm/IntelliJ should solve the issue but if you have to use an older version of the IDE (<= 2019) with Python 3.9, then you can also resolve this issue by selecting the **Inherit global site-packages** option when creating your virtual environment. However, keep in mind that all of your global site-packages will be included in your new environment as a result.

If the error still persists, you may have to install/upgrade setuptools, pip, and distlib in your global site-packages like so,

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade distlib
```

where `pip` can be replaced with `pip3`, `pip3.9`, etc. as needed, and then try creating a virtual environment again with the **Inherit global site-packages** option selected.

Comment: was the setuptools for me. Other posts were missing that

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
import html
html.unescape
```

to replace

```
import HTMLParser
HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape
```