# Pabot not installing for robotframework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I have tried all these commands but pabot is not installing

pip install robotframework-pabot==2.1.0
pip install -U robotframework-pabot
pip3 install -U robotframework-pabot,

It gives this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Python\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gillani Family\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sbflr3y2\\robotframework-pabot_bc7512f7759f42b7b13fa54afa5c11c3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gillani Family\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sbflr3y2\\robotframework-pabot_bc7512f7759f42b7b13fa54afa5c11c3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Gillani Family\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-jrpgswrf'
       cwd: C:\Users\Gillani Family\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sbflr3y2\robotframework-pabot_bc7512f7759f42b7b13fa54afa5c11c3\
  Complete output (11 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
      from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 34, in <module>
      from setuptools.depends import Require
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 7, in <module>
      from .py33compat import Bytecode
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\py33compat.py", line 55, in <module>
      unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
  AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e7/6eabad5bb3166fe6112a40334b52b60938f51ef57a7ad1b82b163a4b0ea5/robotframework-pabot-2.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=68c9edf99bf55ce4ae325c09dac8df9736bfb28023912e86b98a40d951db7621 (from https://pypi.org/simple/robotframework-pabot/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-pabot==2.1.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.30, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.40, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.50, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.60, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.80, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.90, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.12.1, 1.13, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0)   
ERROR: No matching distribution found for robotframework-pabot==2.1.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 'pip3 install netifaces' failing on Debian 10 Buster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040971/why-is-pip3-install-netifaces-failing-on-debian-10-buster)

Comment: update setuptools & pip - the issue is that HTMLParser removed `unescape` with python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

You're requiring version 2.1.0, but the latest version of robotframework-pabot that supports python 2 is 1.13.
Either change your required version of the package or only use python3.

Under the *programming language* section of the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-pabot/#history), you can see which language version the release supports.

Try this command instead:
`pip install -U robotframework-pabot==1.13`
`pip3 install -U robotframework-pabot`

Comment: I am already using python 3.10